# ConnectSessionContainer' declaration must be contained within the <Declarations> tag

Tags: apache-flex, lccs

I tried to follow this example: http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/07/video-chat-for-android-in-30-lines-of-code/ but I still get errors after hours of searching for any solution on the web.

I'am using Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 and Flex 4.5.1 SDK, I also installed the LifeCycle Collaboration Service, and added the lccs.swf to my projects buildpath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:rtc="http://ns.adobe.com/rtc"  currentState="logon" fontSize="28">

<fx:Script>
    [Bindable] private var roomURL:String = "URL HERE!";

    protected function connect():void {
        auth.userName = userName.text;
        currentState = "default";
        session.login();
    }
</fx:Script>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="default"/>
    <s:State name="logon"/>
</s:states>

<fx:Declarations>
    <rtc:AdobeHSAuthenticator id="auth"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:TextInput id="userName" includeIn="logon" top="200" horizontalCenter="0"/>
<s:Button label="Connect" click="connect()" includeIn="logon" top="250" horizontalCenter="0" height="50" width="150"/>

<rtc:ConnectSessionContainer id="session" roomURL="{roomURL}" authenticator="{auth}" autoLogin="false" width="100%" height="100%" includeIn="default">
    <rtc:WebCamera top="10" left="10" bottom="10" right="10"/>
</rtc:ConnectSessionContainer>  

</s:Application>
```

The compiler says following:

> 'ConnectSessionContainer' declaration must be contained within the
>    tag, since it is not assignable to the default
>   property's element type 'mx.core.IVisualElement'.

I'am totaly new to Flex, so dont kill me if there is a simple solution to this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What about `<s:Application>` root tag?

**update:**
Try check [this](http://www.actionscripterrors.com/?p=2167), may be you also have whitespaces.

Comment: Oh sorry, I have that tag in Flash Builder. It seems that I forgot it some how, when I made this thread.

Comment: @opous Could you please then edit your code fragment as it is in Flash Builder?